# Ionic Fab, cross icon for closing the fab is missing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I came across this problem. I tried to find the css in chrome debugger, but no luck. I don't see the cross button like the documentation.

This is the open icon before I press the fab.

[image]

But the closing icon is missing or I can't find it.

[image]

Here is the html

```
<ion-fab bottom right>
  <button class='waiterButton' ion-fab>
    <ion-icon id='waiterIcon' name='custom-waiter'></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
     <button class='callButton' ion-fab>
       <ion-icon id='callIcon' name='custom-bell'></ion-icon>
     </button>
     <button class='billButton' ion-fab>
       <ion-icon id='billIcon' name='custom-bill'></ion-icon>
     </button>
   </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

I have the ionicon in my package.json

```
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.1.4",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
```

In variable.scss

```
// The premium icon font for Ionic. For more info, please see:
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/

@import "ionic.ionicons";
```

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mk6aye Could you check wether you do reference the `ionicons` package in your package.json?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, I think I do reference ionicons in package.json. (updated the question). let me see if reinstalling the ionicon package will help

Comment: Hi, no change after installing the ionicon, but I notice something, I couldnt use any of the icon provided by ionicon, some simple icon like 'home'. could only show the rectagle box :(

Comment: Hmm I guess your ionicons setup is broken somehow. Could you check also if you `@import "ionic.ionicons";` in your variables.scss?

Comment: yup, I checked that last night too,(update the question), and tried to run it whether  with or without that line. I am trying to create a new project to see if the ionicon package is functioning there or not.

Comment: Yeah sounds like a good idea. Ionicons should be working out of the box after creating a new project. If this does not work you could also check with another browser...